# Are Bing Maps apps really this narrowly targeted?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, bing-maps

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846498.aspx, it states: "Set the Active solution platform in Visual Studio to one of the following options. C#, Visual Basic: ARM, x86 or x64"

Does this mean that I can't create a solution that will run on all of these devices/scenarios? I want my app to run on tablets, laptops, and desktops, both x86 and x64... "AnyCPU" is not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"AnyCPU" doesn't mean you'll run on ARM.  It's used for code that will run as either x86 or x64 and so wouldn't include ARM.

However, if you're depending on third party libraries (and especially ones that include unmanaged code) you will often find that you need to pick specifically between x86 and x64 in order to operate with the specific version of the interop library you reference.

That said, x86 apps will run fine on an x64 machine, so you only need differentiate between x86 and ARM.

If you create an app using the WinRT runtime, you should be able to cross-compile for ARM and x86, but it's possible that the Bing Maps API doesn't currently support WinRT.

Comment: I found this: "Today the Bing team announced the release of their WinRT Bing Maps control (BETA) for XAML applications" here: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/06/bing-maps-for-winrt-xaml.aspx